# CSS3 @font-face breaks Razor parser - can it remain inline via a workaround?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, css, razor, font-face

The CSS3 [@font-face rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-rule) breaks a Razor [section](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor) with the error message:  `CS0103: The name 'font' does not exist in the current context`. It crashes at runtime.

It seems the CSS3 `@` character is the problem that causes the Razor parser to fail.

Example:

```
@section HeadCustomStyleBlock {  
    <style type="text/css">  
        @font-face {  
            font-family: Gentium;
            src: url(http://example.com/fonts/Gentium.ttf);            
        }  
    <style>  
}
```

For context, the `@section HeadCustomStyleBlock` is being included in the Layout page's `<head>` element.

**Instead of moving this to an external file, can I implement a workaround to keep it inline?**

Comment: For context, the @section `HeadCustomStyleBlock` is being included in the Layout page's `<head>` element where styles should be put.

Comment: I don't know Razor - maybe just move the CSS into an external `.css` file?

Comment: @Matt: Good point - that would work.  I modified the question slightly because I really want to know if it's possible to keep the CSS inline, or if this is a bonafide Razor issue.  There might be a kind of Razor syntax that I'm overlooking to solve this with inline.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As per ScottGu's blog:

> In cases where the content is valid as code as well (and you want to
>   treat it as content), you can explicitly escape out @ characters by
>   typing @@.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that's the syntactic answer I needed.